# What do these measures mean at the beginning of this choral piece?

Tags: notation, voice, choral, satb

[image: Measures before the start of the piece]

The piece is "Es ist ein Ros entsprungen," and it was composed in the 1600s by Michael Praetorius. This score is edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows the original key and the original clefs and the original note lengths.  It is a so-called "incipit".

Comment: It's interesting that the incipit has the same notes with the same pitch and key and twice the length - but still with the split common time symbol. I might post this as a separate question.

Comment: The so-called "cut time" is often very flexible, particularly in (very) old scores. Here's a reference, which shows at least two different values for "cut time": [http://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory4.htm]